# How to convert this batch queue stored procedure to something usable in SQLite

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlite

I have a SQL stored procedure for getting a batch of results in a queue. I am looking to move to a Sqlite DB, and wondering how I would go about doing it, if possible.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextItemInQueue]
    @LockedBy varchar(75)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare
    @Error                      int,
    @ExitCode                   int,
    @RowCount                   int,
    @PendingStatus              varchar(75),
    @MinutesBeforeBreakLock     int,
    @RequestId                  int,
    @BatchSize                  int

select
    @Error                      = 0,
    @ExitCode                   = 0,
    @RowCount                   = 0,
    @PendingStatus              = 'Pending',
    @MinutesBeforeBreakLock     = 1,
    @BatchSize                  = 100

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION ProcessQueue 

        UPDATE TOP(@BatchSize) UploadQueue WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
        SET
            LockedBy = @LockedBy,
            LockedTime = GETDATE()
        OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.LockedTime, inserted.CompletedTime, inserted.RequestType, inserted.RequestedTime, inserted.Status, inserted.LockedBy, inserted.Data
        WHERE
            STATUS = @PendingStatus
            AND (LockedTime IS NULL OR
            DateDiff(mi, LockedTime, GetDate()) >= @MinutesBeforeBreakLock)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION ProcessQueue

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() > 0
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcessQueue;
    ELSE IF XACT_STATE() < 0
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [does not have stored procedures](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) (or any other control statements).
In an embedded database, this would not make much sense because the code would be executed in the same process anyway.

You have to implement your procedures in whatever language you're using to access the database.

As for queues, SQLites doesn't have them either, because there is no separate server that would run asynchronously from your program.
Just execute the individual SQL commands/queries directly.